# Migrating the SQL and application server from Windows 2003 to Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: java, sql-server, windows, tomcat

We are facing an issue with migrating the application deployed on windows servers 2003.
We use Tomcat 5.5 in app server and SQL server in the SQL box both run on separate Windows server2003.

We were able to successfully deploy the application using Tomcat 5.5 and JDK 1.6 on Windows server 2012 RS2 and also SQL server was migrated to one other instance which also runs on Windows 2012 RS2.

But when the application is launched and when trying to insert data into the DB we are encountering "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

The same application was running fine without any issues on the windows 2003 server which runs on 32 Bit where as the new server is completely 64bit.

Please let me know if I have to install Tomcat 7.0 for Windows2012 or we can still run the application without any issues.

Regards,
Nitin.